# String array as argument in endpoint result in error code 10 in Mandos tests

Tags: blockchain, multiversx

**The problem**

Here's my function :

```
    #[endpoint(registerItem)]
    fn register_item(&self, items_id: &[String])
    {
        // nothing for the moment
    }
```

In my Mandos tests, everything is good (setState, scDeploy, etc..) until I test the call of this endpoint like so :

```
{
  "step": "scCall",
  "tx": {
    "from": "address:owner",
    "to": "sc:equip",
    "function": "registerItem",
    "arguments": [

        "0x70757461696e|0x70757461696e"

    ],
    "gasLimit": "5,000,000",
    "gasPrice": "0"
  },
  "expect": {
    "status": "0",
    "gas": "*",
    "refund": "*"
  }
}
```

When I run it, I got the error code 10 aka execution failed.

This is the entire log :

```
Output: Scenario: init.scen.json ...   FAIL: result code mismatch. Tx . Want: 0. Have: 10 (execution failed). Message: execution failed
Done. Passed: 0. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0.
ERROR: some tests failed
```

** Things I have tried **

I have replaced the strings array with an int array and I didn't get this problem. I also tried [str] but I got this error :

```
15 | #[elrond_wasm::derive::contract]
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
```

Comment: Using string type in smart contracts is generally regarded as bad practice. You should use ManagedBuffer wherever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a endpoint I think you have to use SDK special type for that like ManagedVec so that Node can know how to serialize/deserialize it.

So maybe try this :

```
    #[endpoint(registerItem)]
    fn register_item(&self, items_id: ManagedVec<ManagedBuffer>)
    {
        // nothing for the moment
    }
```